# Publishing to a topic on ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Canot publishing to JMS topic, ActiveMQ, java. The code is basic but it errors:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
    
ActiveMQSession session = (ActiveMQSession) connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = ((TopicSession) session).createTopic(subject);
ActiveMQMessageProducer producer = (ActiveMQMessageProducer) session.createProducer(topic);
    
     
ActiveMQTextMessage txtmessage = (ActiveMQTextMessage) session.createTextMessage();
txtmessage.setText(readFileAsString("foo.txt",null));
    
    
producer.send(txtmessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.getDestination()Ljavax/jms/Destination;
```

`NoSuchMethodError` is always indication that you have wrong version (either lower version (or) higher version) of client jars in your client classpath.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I think if jar is not present at all, I think it would be ClassNotFoundException, isn't it? If possible, can you provide any reference to support your comment?